# JS - How to get URL of redirect

Tags: javascript, api, url

Hi I'm trying to find a way to get the URL of a redirected webpage.

Ex/ I type in a url to my web browser, "http:foo.com", and it redirects me to "http://foo.com/bar".

How can I use fetch or something else to have "http://foo.com/bar" returned to me? (The website I'm trying to receive the url from "has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Please and thanks in advance for ideas / solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `XMLHttpRequest` and `fetch` silently follow redirects, and no information about the final URL is available in the object afterwards.

Even if that information was available, the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) would prevent you from accessing it (as [the error message indicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-https-www-website-com/35553666#35553666)).

---

Use a server side technology instead.

Comment: Can you recommend a server side technology for that?  I'm actually trying to do it within a seneca.js microservice.  Sorry If I should have explained further.

Comment: You can set `redirect` to different handling with Fetch.  https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#requestredirect  Upon a successful response, you can also determine what the final URL was by inspecting the response object.

Comment: If you were doing it in Seneca on Node.js, then you wouldn't trigger the CORS error message which is a browser specific error. You should be able to use Node to do this.